# JavaScript timestamp to Python datetime conversion

Tags: javascript, python, timestamp

To get timestamp in JavaScript we use

```
var ts = new Date().getTime()
```

What is the proper way to convert it to a Python `datetime` so far I use the following code

```
>>> jsts = 1335205804950
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(jsts/1000)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 24, 0, 30, 4)
```

I divide timestamp by 1000 because I get error like

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
1 d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a)
ValueError: year is out of range
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Your current method is correct, dividing by 1000 is necessary because your JavaScript returns the timestamp in milliseconds, and `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` expects a timestamp in seconds.

To preserve the millisecond accuracy you can divide by `1000.0`, so you are using float division instead of integer division:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(jsts/1000.0)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 23, 11, 30, 4, 950000)
```

Comment: Thankfully, this isn't necessary in Python 3.

Comment: @delnan I have the same issue in python3: `datetime.fromtimestamp(1485373592240)` fails unless divided by `1000`

Comment: @jjj I think he meant the float division isn't necessary in python 3.x; we have an explicit integer division operator - `//` - so if you divide a `float` by an `int` with `/` you get a `float`.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue, thanks to @andrew-clark for the answer, i've build a small example to handle both cases:

```
     try:
        # when timestamp is in seconds
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    except (ValueError):
        # when timestamp is in miliseconds
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

For others still getting an error: I had a similar issue but the unix timestamp was in microseconds, i.e. I had to divide the timestamp by 1000000 to get the correct result.

```
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1502360499615921)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it is the correct way, because js includes milliseconds in the date/time. Python (and PHP) as far as I know, don't.
For more precision you could use `/1000.0`.