# Pandas: Convert Timestamp to datetime.date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I have a pandas column of Timestamp data

```
In [27]: train["Original_Quote_Date"][6] 
Out[27]: Timestamp('2013-12-25 00:00:00')
```

How can check equivalence of these objects to `datetime.date` objects of the type

```
datetime.date(2013, 12, 25)
```

Comment: See also the related question for *datetime*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use the `.date` method:

```
In [11]: t = pd.Timestamp('2013-12-25 00:00:00')

In [12]: t.date()
Out[12]: datetime.date(2013, 12, 25)

In [13]: t.date() == datetime.date(2013, 12, 25)
Out[13]: True
```

---

To compare against a DatetimeIndex (i.e. an array of Timestamps), you'll want to do it the other way around:

```
In [21]: pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2013, 12, 25))
Out[21]: Timestamp('2013-12-25 00:00:00')

In [22]: ts = pd.DatetimeIndex([t])

In [23]: ts == pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2013, 12, 25))
Out[23]: array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: For an entire column or series, just use this in conjunction with an apply method and lambda.  For example, if t is a series of timestamps:  t.apply(lambda x: x.date())

Comment: It is worth to mention that the time part is _lost_ and only date part is kept. For those who need to keep time, use `.to_pydatetime()` as mentioned by Xavier Ho.

Comment: There is a corresponding `.time()` method that drops the date and returns just the `datetime.time` component

Answer (score 34):

As of pandas 0.20.3, use [`.to_pydatetime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_pydatetime.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_pydatetime) to convert any `pandas.DateTimeIndex` instances to Python `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: Worth noting that for large DatetimeIndexs this can be slow / lot of memory. This is because a DatetimeIndex is basically just a light wrapper around an array of int64s, whilst an array of python datetimes is an array of fully-fledged python objects/not compactly laid out.

Answer (score 7):

You can convert a datetime.date object into a pandas Timestamp like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
import datetime

# create a datetime data object
d_time = datetime.date(2010, 11, 12)

# create a pandas Timestamp object
t_stamp = pd.to_datetime('2010/11/12')

# cast `datetime_timestamp` as Timestamp object and compare
d_time2t_stamp = pd.to_datetime(d_time)

# print to double check
print(d_time)
print(t_stamp)
print(d_time2t_stamp)

# since the conversion succeds this prints `True`
print(d_time2t_stamp == t_stamp)
```

Answer (score 7):

Assume time column is in timestamp integer msec format

1 day = 86400000 ms

Here you go:

```
day_divider = 86400000

df['time'] = df['time'].values.astype(dtype='datetime64[ms]') # for msec format

df['time'] = (df['time']/day_divider).values.astype(dtype='datetime64[D]') # for day format
```

Answer (score 6):

I've used the way recommended by Filomeno Gonzalez, albeit with a slight twist:

```
 data['date'] = data['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
```

Comment: This returns an error `'int' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: @HomBahrani that probably happens because your column type is int, unlike the original user input

Answer (score 6):

```
from datetime import datetime

time = datetime.fromtimestamp(1676266245263 / 1000)
```

Example Output :
2023-02-13 05:30:45.263000

Answer (score 3):

So, got this from an IBM coursera tutorial.

```py
data['date'] = data['TimeStamp'].apply(lambda d: datetime.date.fromtimestamp(d))
```

Comment: This can also be shortened to `data['date'] = data['TimeStamp'].apply(datetime.date.fromtimestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

If I have a pandas DataFrame with timestamp column (`1546300800000, 1546301100000, 1546301400000, 1546301700000, 1546302000000`) and I want to convert this into date time format

```
import datetime

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000.0))
```

This will return a column with the format `2019-01-01 00:00:00, 2019-01-01 00:05:00, 2019-01-01 00:10:00, 2019-01-01 00:15:00, 2019-01-01 00:20:00`...etc

Dividing by 1000 to convert from ms to s as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548132/python-datetime-fromtimestamp-yielding-valueerror-year-out-of-range)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the epochs as a normal "column" (i.e. it wasn't a `TimeSeries`).

I converted it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'] / 1000, unit='s')
```

Time was in milliseconds, so I needed to divide by a thousand. I set the `unit='s'` to mention that the `Timestamp` is in seconds (you can, however, use `unit='ms'` if you don't want to divide by 1000, or depending on your original `Timestamp` unit).

#### A sample result

```
1673885284000 becomes 2023-01-16 4:08:04
```