# Set date time format of x-axis in Pandas-Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib

As in title, I am trying to change the datetime format of my graph. I have done some research and found 2 lines that I have included in my code (#option 1 and #option 2). They give no error but the output format is not the one I have specified. Please, read code below and see loaded image. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks.
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from datetime import datetime


# create an array of 5 dates starting at '2020-02-24', one every month
rng = pd.date_range('2020-02-24', periods=5, freq='MS')
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))})
df_1.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))})
df_2.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
print(df_1, "\n")
print(df_2)

#Set up figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(11,5))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.3, hspace=None) #Adjust space between graphs

#Plot 1
df_1.plot(ax=ax[0], kind="line", color="forestgreen", stacked=False, rot=90)
ax[0].set_axisbelow(True)  # To put plot grid below plots
ax[0].yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax[0].xaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
# option 1
ax[0].set_xticklabels([pandas_datetime.strftime("%d %b %Y") for pandas_datetime in df_1.index])
# option 2
ax[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d %b %Y'))
ax[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)  # Put legend on top
ax[0].set(xlabel=None, ylabel="Amount %")  # Set axis label


#Plot 2
df_2.plot(ax=ax[1], kind='line', stacked=False, color="violet", rot=90)
ax[1].set_axisbelow(True)  # To put plot grid below plots
ax[1].yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax[1].xaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
# option 1
ax[1].set_xticklabels([pandas_datetime.strftime("%d %b %Y") for pandas_datetime in df_2.index])
# option 2
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d %b %Y'))
ax[1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)  # Put legend on top
ax[1].set(xlabel=None, ylabel="Amount %")  # Set axis label


#Save file as png
date_now = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
fig.savefig("Test_{}.png".format(date_now), bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the fixes for your options:

- Option 1 (with `strftime`): you can use `set_xticks` to also enforce the correct tick positions.
- Option 2 (with `mdates`): you should a) specify a `MonthLocator` and b) you need to convert your index so you they are `datetime.date`, not `datetime.datetime`.  This is an annoying issue [I posted about in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62326811/13386979).  This is not an issue if you do the plotting all from `matplotlib`, but doing it through `pandas` apparently it is.

Here's the full code and output, with plot 1 using option 1 and plot 2 using option 2.  There are still little differences between these 2 options that can be formatted away (oddly the option 2 ticks come out vertical, while the option 1 were not):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MonthLocator
from datetime import datetime


# create an array of 5 dates starting at '2020-02-24', one every month
rng = pd.date_range('2020-02-24', periods=5, freq='MS')
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))})
df_1.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))})
df_2.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
print(df_1, "\n")
print(df_2)

#Set up figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(11,5))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.3, hspace=None) #Adjust space between graphs

#Plot 1
df_1.plot(ax=ax[0], kind="line", color="forestgreen", stacked=False, rot=90)
ax[0].set_axisbelow(True)  # To put plot grid below plots
ax[0].yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax[0].xaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
# option 1
ax[0].set_xticks([pandas_datetime.strftime("%d %b %Y") for pandas_datetime in df_1.index])
ax[0].set_xticklabels([pandas_datetime.strftime("%d %b %Y") for pandas_datetime in df_1.index])

ax[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)  # Put legend on top
ax[0].set(xlabel=None, ylabel="Amount %")  # Set axis label


#Plot

#SEE THIS NEW LINE!!!
df_2.index = [pd.to_datetime(date).date() for date in df_2.index]

df_2.plot(ax=ax[1], kind='line', stacked=False, color="violet", rot=90)
ax[1].set_axisbelow(True)  # To put plot grid below plots
ax[1].yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax[1].xaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')

# option 2
#see new line before df_2.plot
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d %b %Y'))
plt.xticks(rotation=0, fontsize=8)

ax[1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)  # Put legend on top
ax[1].set(xlabel=None, ylabel="Amount %")  # Set axis label
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom! Very useful and thanks also fo the explanation.

Comment: If I want to change the line plots into bar plots, how can I define the months as the x-axis category?

Answer (score 0):

To customize DateTime Index in a bar plot using Pandas and Matplotlib I have found the following solution, which can be used with the code above:

```
#Plot 1
df_1.plot(ax=ax[0], kind="bar", color="forestgreen", stacked=False, rot=90)
ax[0].set_axisbelow(True)  # To put plot grid below plots
ax[0].yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax[0].xaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')

#Grab xticklabels after plotting
ticks = [tick.get_text() for tick in ax[0].get_xticklabels()]
ticks = pd.to_datetime(ticks).strftime('%b %Y')
ax[0].set_xticklabels(ticks)

ax[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)  # Put legend on top
ax[0].set(xlabel=None, ylabel="Amount %")  # Set axis label
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Many thanks.