# Date does not get displayed in the desired format in line chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a plot_graph() function that plots pandas dataframe as a line chart.

```
def plot_graph(df):
 ax = plt.gca()
 #df["Date"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
 #df["date"] = df["date"].astype('datetime64[ns]')
 print(df['date'])
 df.plot(kind='line', x='date', y='Actual', ax=ax)
 df.plot(kind='line', x='date', y='Expected', color='red', ax=ax)
 ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))
 plt.savefig("fig1.png")
```

I pass pandas dataframe in this format

```
 date       actual   expected
 2019-11    20       65
 2019-12    35       65
```

When I plot the line chart, x axis labels does not get displayed correctly as in (yyyy-mm) format. I believe it is with the date format. So I tried converting it to date. I tried with all the options(commented in the code), nothing seems to work. Any suggestions would be appreicated.

Comment: Use Matplotlib's [DateFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter)?

Comment: @QuangHoang: It doesnt work as well

Comment: Your `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))` looks really dangerous :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang: ok, it was one of my tries, it did not work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def plot_graph(df):
    ax = plt.gca()
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
    df.plot(kind='line', x='date', y='actual', ax=ax)
    df.plot(kind='line', x='date', y='expected', color='red', ax=ax)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
    # ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')) #to explicitly set format
    
plot_graph(df)
```

[image]

I think using `matplotlib.dates` is the best thing here, **but** it seems like `df.plot()` needs dates to be *date* and *not datetime* (or string).  If you instead plot directly through `matplotlib` you don't need to do this.  [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62326811/13386979).

Answer (score 1):

- Reference [Matplotlib: Date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html) & [Formatting date ticks using ConciseDateFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html)

  - [matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator)
  - [matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter)
  - [matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator.html)
  - [matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_major_formatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_major_formatter.html)
- Note the `index` column is in a datetime format. To transform your column to datetime, use `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)`
- `df.plot()` has tick locs like `array([13136, 13152, 13174, 13175], dtype=int64)`.  I don't actually know how those numbers are derived, but they cause an issue with some of the matplotlib axis and date formatting methods, which is why I changed the plots away from `df.plot`.
- `sns.lineplot` and `plt.plot` have tick locs that are the ordinal representation of the datetime, `array([737553., 737560., 737567., 737577., 737584., 737591., 737598., 737607.]`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # for test data
from datetime import datetime  # for test data
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# synthetic data with date as a datetime
np.random.seed(365)
length = 700
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(length, 2) * 10, columns=['Actual', 'Expected'], index=pd.bdate_range(datetime.today(), freq='d', periods=length).tolist()).reset_index()

# display(df.head())
       index    Actual  Expected
0 2020-07-16  9.414557  6.416027
1 2020-07-17  6.846105  5.885621
2 2020-07-18  5.438872  3.680709
3 2020-07-19  7.666258  3.050124
4 2020-07-20  4.420860  1.104433


# function
def plot_graph(df):
    
    #  df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)  # if needed and date is the column name

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
    months_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')   # format

    ax.plot('index', 'Actual', data=df)
    ax.plot('index', 'Expected', data=df, color='red')

    # format the ticks
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(months_fmt)
    
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()


plot_graph(df)
```

[image]