# How to pass each row of a dataFrame to an array

Tags: python, pandas

How to add a dataframe row in a field array
Like i have my data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':100}, {'c1':11,'c2':110}, {'c1':12,'c2':120}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print df
```

Output:

```
   c1   c2
0  10  100
1  11  110
2  12  120
```

So i want to have something like this  :

```
{
  "fields": {
        "c1": 10,
        "c2": 100,
   }
},
{
  "fields": {
        "c1": 11,
        "c2": 110,
   }
},
{
  "fields": {
        "c1": 12,
        "c2": 120,
   }
}
```

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try chain with `df.to_dict`

```
d = [{'field' : x} for x in df.to_dict('records')]
Out[167]: 
[{'field': {'c1': 10, 'c2': 100}},
 {'field': {'c1': 11, 'c2': 110}},
 {'field': {'c1': 12, 'c2': 120}}]
```

Comment: I guess using short-forms is scheduled for deprecation in the next version. Might want to mention it as in newer versions it might raise `Exception`, the latest version throws `FutureWarning`. Works like charm in older versions.

Comment: Thanks BENY, but 'r' parameter is deprecated as Ch3steR said.So i changed the 'r' to 'records' and it worked perfectly .Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
a = df.transpose().to_dict()
a
>>> {0: {'c1': 10, 'c2': 100}, 1: {'c1': 11, 'c2': 110}, 2: {'c1': 12, 'c2': 120}}
res = [{'fields': a[i]} for i in a]
res
>>> [{'fields': {'c1': 10, 'c2': 100}}, {'fields': {'c1': 11, 'c2': 110}}, {'fields': {'c1': 12, 'c2': 120}}]
```

As @anky points out, defining `a` like so: `a = df.to_dict('index')` will also work, not sure which is more computationally efficient

Comment: This method changes my column date to timestamp.From 2020-01-03 to Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),How can i fix that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386751/pandas-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-date

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient` as `records`.

```
out = df.to_dict(orient='records')
# [{'c1': 10, 'c2': 100}, {'c1': 11, 'c2': 110}, {'c1': 12, 'c2': 120}]
out = [{'fields': val} for val in out]

[{'fields': {'c1': 10, 'c2': 100}},
 {'fields': {'c1': 11, 'c2': 110}},
 {'fields': {'c1': 12, 'c2': 120}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' built in method `to_dict()` allows converting a dataframe to a serialized list of records. Your desired output would require a transformation on these records:

```
# Get each row as a record
records = df.to_dict(orient='records')
# [{'c1': 10, 'c2': 100}, {'c1': 11, 'c2': 110}, {'c1': 12, 'c2': 120}]

# Transform each row
records = [{'fields':x} for x in records]
# [{'fields': {'c1': 10, 'c2': 100}},
# {'fields': {'c1': 11, 'c2': 110}},
# {'fields': {'c1': 12, 'c2': 120}}]
```