# Converting a numpy float64 data type into 2 lists

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to convert the following code's output into 2 lists, dates and prices, which contain the dates and prices that are outputted as a dtype:float64

```
from pandas_datareader import data
def get_stock_data(ticker, start, end):
    stock_data = data.DataReader(ticker, start=start, end=end, data_source='yahoo')['Close']
    return stock_data

print(get_stock_data('TSLA', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-31'))
```

stock_data.tolist() gives me the prices but how do I get the dates?

This could be any arbitrary set of start and end dates so I don't want to manually create a list for one test case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the return is a Pandas series and the dates are the index `stock_data.index.tolist()`.

Comment: This might help you convert to regular datetime object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386751/pandas-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-date

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be modified a bit to get two different lists of dates and prices. I have converted the `stock_data` into a pandas dataframe and extracted the lists of dates and prices from the dataframe as follows:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
def get_stock_data(ticker, start, end):
    stock_data = data.DataReader(ticker, start=start, end=end, data_source='yahoo')['Close']
    df = pd.DataFrame(stock_data)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    dates = df["Date"].astype(str).tolist()
    prices = df["Close"].tolist()
    
    return dates, prices

get_stock_data('TSLA', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-31')
```