# Python's datetime.min with time zone (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

If I do:

```
>>> datetime.max.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> datetime.min.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

However:

```
datetime.min.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286224/javascript-timestamp-to-python-datetime-conversion) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548132/python-datetime-fromtimestamp-yielding-valueerror-year-out-of-range) answers, it seems a conversion issue.

Is this a bug or an intended behaviour, and why?

Comment: Why would you have to use `astimezone`? if you just need datetime.min / .max as a placeholder as aware datetime, `replace` does the trick. Python's naive datetime resembling *something like* local time brings some complications with it, this is one of them IIUC. One could argue about if this was a good design decision or not. But a bug existing still in 3.11 suggests there's no easy solution on the way.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug, still open in Python 3.8: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/75395

Comment: the comments on this issue still don't answer your question *why* I think ;-)