# Why Javascript's Date(timestamp) and Python's datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp) differ?

Tags: javascript, python, date

I have the following timestamp in JS: **1436428916900**
When I enter this date in JS I got the following results:

> > Date(1436428916900)
> >         "Tue Feb 16 2016 20:09:42 GMT+0200 (EET)"

I found several questions on SO and most of them offer following solution:

```
import datetime
my_time = 1436428916900
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(my_time / 1e3)
```

But the problem is that this code results in the following result :

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 9, 11, 1, 56, 900000)
```

which is absolutely different result from JS code.

Sources : [JavaScript timestamp to Python datetime conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286224/javascript-timestamp-to-python-datetime-conversion)

[How to convert integer timestamp to Python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime)

Comment: The date Python is giving for that timestamp is correct, and date you're getting in JavaScript is wrong - you can confirm this at http://www.unixtimestamp.com or using the *nix date utility. What's the exact JavaScript code you're using?

Comment: Are you saying the dates are wrong? or the formatting?

Comment: Try `new Date(…)` instead of `Date(…)` in JavaScript.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505693/difference-between-datedatestring-and-new-datedatestring

Comment: `Date(...)`doesn't accept timestamp. It just returns a string representing current time. You'll know - just repeatedly enter `Date(1436428916900)` quickly and you'll see what I'm saying. `new Date(1436428916900)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @SvenMarnach—what difference do you expect that will make?

Comment: @CajetanRodrigues—the [*ECMAScript Language Specification*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value) disagrees with you. When *Date* is called as a function with a single value that is Type number, it is assumed to be a time value. The function returns an implementation dependent string for the date generated from the value. It also accepts numbers and objects.

Comment: @RobG got it, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @RobG The difference I expect is that `new Date(timestamp)` works as expected, while `Date(timestamp)` doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaScript function `Date()` is different from the `Date` constructor invoked by `new Date(…)`.  The function silently ignores any parameters and returns a string representing the current time instead of a new `Date` instance. (See the [EcmaScript 2015 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor) for further reference.)

So you should use `new Date(timestamp)` in JavaScript, and you will get the same result in Python and JavaScript.

JavaScript is quite a special language.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think that the problem is in JS code.

Comment: "*The function only accepts a date string…*" is misleading. It also accepts a time value number and objects such as date instances (see [*ECMA-262 §20.3.2.2*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value)).

Comment: @RobG What you linked seems to be the documentation of the `Date` constructor, not of `Date()` when called as a function.  I don't know where the latter is documented in the standard (or whether it's mentioned at all).  However, I tried with Firefox, Chrome and NodeJS, and for neither of them `Date(timestamp)` works in any meaningful way.  It always returns a date string referring to the current time, regardless of the value of the timestamp passed in.  The only reference I have is the answer I linked.

Comment: @RobG: I found the [reference in the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor): "When Date is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it returns a String representing the current time (UTC)."  It always returns the current date, and doesn't accept any argument at all.  I'll correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: @SvenMarnach—ECMAScript 2015 is more confusing than previous versions in many respects, this is one more. Who would have thought that "*Date ( value ) … When the Date function is called…*" really means `new Date (value)` (which is how it was written in previous versions)?