# how to convert epoch to date time by assigning it a value to it using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

how to convert epoch to time by assigning a particular epoch value to it. tried assigning values to a and calling it. couldnt able to do it.

```
import datetime

a=1529396478000

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a).strftime('%c')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript timestamp to Python datetime conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286224/javascript-timestamp-to-python-datetime-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

a=1529396478000
a /= 1000

print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(a).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

I think a is missing a dot, `a=1529396478.000` otherwise the year is 50434 resulting in a ValueError.

Comment: got it thanks! is there an way of doing it using pandas without adding ( . )

Comment: @hukkemaaru - Looking at the error I think you are running python 3.6 on a windows system and triggered a resolved bug : https://bugs.python.org/issue29097.

Please update python and try again, the code works and you should not recieve this error.